# How to display a View Block based on number of characters in Body?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I currently have a view that creates an "About the Author" box that pulls information from the user's profile and displays the appropriate author box based on the author of the node (content). I only want to display it on nodes that have a minimum amount of characters in the body of the node. (It currently displays for all nodes the block is enabled for.)

The desired result is that long pieces of content have an "About the Author" box, while short pieces of content do not.

The problem I am having is that when I select the filter criteria for the view, the body field for the node is not listed, so I cannot filter off of it. And I do not see any other way to test how long the content is, in order to determine whether the "About the Author" block should display or not.

How can I make it so the Author Box only appears on long content (i.e. content body > 1000 characters)?

Comment: do you solve your problem?

Comment: you're welcome and good luck with your projects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Views Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_conditional) module. Configure your field to ***Exclude from display*** and ***Apply***

[image]

Then add the ***Views: Views Conditional*** field and configure like this (but with your condition) and ***Apply***

[image]

**EDIT (after [No Sssweat comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/27710/no-sssweat))**:You can combine in your view the [Views Field View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module to embed a view (your block if you want) as a field in the view.

Comment: I think you misread the question. From how I understood the question, I am afraid he only wants to display the **about the author view** if the node's body is grater than "x". This answer does not address the displaying/printing the **about the author view** part.